# graph homomorphism

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two non-bipartite graphs. We know that, if $\exists$ homomorphism $\phi : G \rightarrow H$, then $\omega(G) \le \omega(H)$ where $\omega$ is clique number.

$(1)$ Does the converse hold in general?

$(2)$ Under what conditions does the converse hold?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\omega(G) \leq \omega(H)$?

Comment: corrected now!!

Comment: Notice that there are similar inequalities for the chromatic number, independence number, odd girth etc. Even if all these are satisfied, a homomorphism is still not guaranteed.

Comment: Hi the second part of the question is under what conditions, can one expect a homomorphism?

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi: Is there an inequality related to independence number? Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have your inequality backwards, I believe.

If $\omega(G) \le \omega(H)$, it does not follow in general that there is a homomorphism from $G\to H$. There are many triangle-free graphs with chromatic number greater than four, none of these will admit a homomorphism to $K_4$.